# Python Hellinger formula explanation

Tags: python, for-loop

I was looking up some formulas for Hellinger's distance between distributions, and I found one (in Python) that I've never seen similar format for. I am confused how it works.

```
def hellinger(p,q):
    """Hellinger distance between distributions"""
    return sum([(sqrt(t[0])-sqrt(t[1]))*(sqrt(t[0])-sqrt(t[1]))\
                for t in zip(p,q)])/sqrt(2.)
```

I've never seen this kind of... format before. They are dividing by a for statement? I mean.. how does this even work?

Comment: This constuct is named [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the backslash is for line continuation.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh that's not a forward slash - I'm an idiot, I was so confused. Thanks for pointing that out.

That doesn't relieve me of my confusion though - only new questions arise. The `t` is defined in the for-statement, yet it appears before it... how does python allow for that?

Comment: Check out the above link to the list comprehension documentation. Then you will understand how it works.

Comment: Note that the backslash is unnecessary in this case. It's also poorly written, as squaring the difference will be more efficient than recomputing the square roots. `sum((sqrt(x)-sqrt(y))**2 for x,y in zip(p,q))/sqrt(2.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a faible for distance measures, hence I made a [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Teagum/460a508cda99f9874e4ff828e1896862) with some implementations of Hellinger distance.

Regarding your question, the construct is called a [list comrehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the backslash is just for line continuation.

Here is a possible listing without list comprehension:

```
def hellinger_explicit(p, q):
    """Hellinger distance between two discrete distributions.
       Same as original version but without list comprehension
    """
    list_of_squares = []
    for p_i, q_i in zip(p, q):

        # caluclate the square of the difference of ith distr elements
        s = (math.sqrt(p_i) - math.sqrt(q_i)) ** 2

        # append 
        list_of_squares.append(s)

    # calculate sum of squares
    sosq = sum(list_of_squares)    

    return sosq / math.sqrt(2)
```

Comment: Here, p and q passed to hellinger_explicit function are two data vectors or their probability distributions? My data vectors are floating point. Will this function work for them?

Comment: The function assumes that p and q are probability distributions.

Comment: Then can you give an idea on how can I get these densities for my data vectors  that have continuous values.

Comment: @MaxPowers... On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance, in the section of "discrete distributions", the Hellinger distance is written as```H(P,Q) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left(\sqrt{p_i}-\sqrt{q_i} \right)^2}``` (you can copy and paste it on https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/). Shouldn't the last line of code includes the square root of ```sosq```, i.e. ```return math.sqrt(sosq)/ math.sqrt(2)```?